# French Accents are not properly displayed everywhere in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

I have a strings.xml file for french variant. The texts with accents are displayed in some activities and not in other. The accent for small letters are displayed everywhere. But for capital letter, Its not displaying properly in few screens. Ex: I am trying to display "Àréussi DÉTAILS" and I am getting "Aréussi DETAILS". The problem is not happening everywhere in app. I have compared the contents from working layout file and non working layout file. nothings seemed to help.

I have checked the encoding. its utf-8, even the xml version and encoding line is also added in all the layout files. the font family used is "avenirnextltpro_demi".

Can someone please help me with identifying the issue and resolution. The previous similar answers in stack overflow didn't help much.